# ProcessBuilder executes one command from the String list but doesn't executes the next one.

Tags: java, bash, processbuilder

I am a newbie in programming. I created a String list for ProcessBuilder. ProcessBuilder is executing one command from the String list (and successfully writes a file I asked to write) but doesn't execute the next String command. Here is the code:

```
List<String> vsArrays = new ArrayList<String>();
vsArrays.add("/bin/sh");
vsArrays.add("-c");
vsArrays.add("echo '123' > ~/1.rad");
vsArrays.add("echo '123' > ~/2.rad");
vsArrays.add("echo '123' > ~/3.rad");

for (String s : vsArrays){
 system.out.println(s);
}

ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder(vsArrays);
Process start = proc.start();
start.waitFor();
```

The first file (named 1.rad) is created in the home (~) directory but the following files are not. Although I managed to execute the next commands (and write the other files) by using redirectInput from a file, but I dont want to create a separate file for redirectInput. Can you please answer why the next commands (from the string list) are not getting executed? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProcessBuilder` was never meant to execute multiple commands. The entries of the `List` are treated as arguments and it is the invoked program `sh` which executes the one argument due to the `-c` option. So it’s the `sh` command and it’s `-c` option which “decide” to interpret one argument, and only one, as a command to start. But the bash will run multiple commands being provided as a single argument separated by `;`.

```
List<String> vsArrays = new ArrayList<String>();
vsArrays.add("/bin/sh");
vsArrays.add("-c");
vsArrays.add("echo '123' > ~/1.rad; echo '123' > ~/2.rad; echo '123' > ~/3.rad");

ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder(vsArrays);
Process start = proc.start();
start.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used process builder for a while, but I believe you are passing the 4 last strings as arguments to the first string (the executable). In which case, I'm not sure the command you have constructed i valid syntax. Try something like (haven't tested the code myself but should give you some ideas):

```
private void myMainFunction() {
  doWrite("1.rad");
  doWrite("2.rad");
  doWrite("3.rad");
}

private void doWrite(String filename) {
  List<String> vsArrays = new ArrayList<String>();
  vsArrays.add("/bin/sh");
  vsArrays.add("-c");
  vsArrays.add("echo '123' > ~/" + filename);

  for (String s : vsArrays){
    system.out.println(s);
  }

  ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder(vsArrays);
  Process start = proc.start();
  start.waitFor();
}
```